# Can't get the find command in Excel 2008 to work

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, excel-2008

I want to use AppleScript to find a TAG cell I put next to sets of data, so that I can then link to those values on a separate results sheet.

At the moment all I get is errors telling me that this, that and the other doesn't understand find. Here's the script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active workbook
        activate object worksheet "1001"
        tell sheet "1001"
            set searchRange to used range
            tell searchRange
                (find searchRange what "TAG")
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I'm a complete beginner with this so completely stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works very well for me: (this code goes between `tell sheet "1001"` and `end tell`):

```
set searchRange to used range
try
    set foundRange to find searchRange what "blurp" with match case
    (* do something with the foundRange *)
on error -- not found
    (* do error handling *)
end try
```

If it finds `"blurp"`, a range is returned (something like `range "'[Workbook1]1001'!$D$4" of application "Microsoft Excel"`), otherwise an error is thrown (which simply means that what you searched for was not found).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I've not given it anything to do with the range it found!